# does not("!") operator valid everywhere?

Tags: c++, if-statement, conditional-statements, operator-keyword

the code below will

> calls a member function of the Sales_item object named item1. -C++ Primer 4th edi.(book)

```
// first check that item1 and item2 represent the same book
if (item1.same_isbn(item2))
```

which will return true if ISBN of `item1 is equal to item2`, but thee give some exercise which make me want to use opposite effect to the original condition, not equal(obviously), so I put it like this

```
if (!item1.same_isbn(item2))
```

the compiler will compile but the result miss from the expected one, so there something that told me that where code is valid, but processing something that I'm not expected.

so, per title said, does the not("!") operator actually work the same everywhere?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong here, but are you saying that `if (!item1.same_isbn(item2)) { foo(); }` never executes `foo` when item1 matches item2?

Comment: Are you sure that `item1.same_isbn(item2)` is returning a boolean (true or false) value? What do you get if you do `cout << item1.same_isbn(item2);` on the line before the `if` statement?

Comment: It operates consistently over every operand for which it is defined. In the case of `!item1.same_isbn(item2)`, what is the operand to the `!` operator? What is the type? Is `!` defined over that type?

Comment: Mike Bantegui, yes, I'm trying to say that...
@Gaurav, yes, I'm sure, it return '1'(which indicate true in boolean value)  when the ISBN is equal between the two item.

Comment: @Vastor: Awesome. What does it return when the two ISBNs are different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `!` unary operator can be applied to any scalar (numeric or pointer) expression.  The operand is converted to `bool`, and the result is true if the expression is false, and false if it's true.

For a numeric operand, `!x` is equivalent to `x != 0`.  It's the same for a pointer operand (it's true if the pointer is a null pointer.)

It can also be applied to an expression of any type for which there's a conversion to `bool`, or, of course, for any type for which an overloaded `operator !` is defined.

Comment: I'll take that as `!item1.same_isbn(item2)` will return true if the `ISBN in item1 and item 2` NOT equal...

Answer (score 0):

in this example:

```
if (!item1.same_isbn(item2))
{
    //execute this branch if item1.same_isbn(item2) == false
}
else
{
    //execute this branch if item1.same_isbn(item2) == true
}
```

The above statement will evaluate to true if `item1.same_isbn(item2)` is equal to false.

Comment: As long as operator ! is not defined for the return type of item1.same_isbn to do something else.

Answer (score 0):

Try

> if ( ! ( item1.same_isbn(item2)))

Note : make sure `item1.same_isbn(item2)` returns a `true` or `false`

Comment: @Vastor check this, `item1.same_isbn(item2)` and make sure what it returns.

Comment: i put it like this
`std::cout << item1.same_isbn(item2)`
and it return 1, which indicate as true